# Any practical Single Sign-On (SSO) protocol/traffic analysis tool/method/analyzer?

Tags: authentication, sso, saml, openid

I want to analyze the SSO protocol/traffic that is deployed in real environment, such as commercial website. The challenge is that most of them are black-box.

**Scenario 1**. I read several papers about SSO analysis. Most of them developed own SSO traffic analyzer, which can turn SSO-related HTTP traffic into human readable format. But they normally do not explain technical details and publish their tools.

**Scenario 2**. Another method someone advised me [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152641/is-it-possible-to-analyze-real-single-sign-on-sso-messages-via-network-sniffin) is to analyze through web browser debugger. But the challenge is that: 1. the HTTP traffic shown in debugger is not human readable; 2. too many HTTP traffic to focus SSO related only.

**Scenario 3**. I tried several browser add-on, such as SAML Tracer (chrome) and SSO Tracer (firefox). It was useful to trace SSO traffic in [demo website](https://saml-federation.appspot.com/saml/discovery?returnIDParam=idp&entityID=saml-federation.appspot.com) only, but failed in commercial websites, such as Google/Facebook/Yahoo-login enabled websites (SSO service providers for openid/saml IDP).

My questions are:

1. What is the reason for scenario 3?
2. Please suggest practical methodology to analyze SSO traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the presentation on SSO theory -- [PDF] https://www.compass-security.com/fileadmin/Datein/Research/Praesentationen/area41_2016_saml.pdf [PDF] -- that introduced the SAMLRaider BApp for Burp Suite -- http://www.toolswatch.org/2015/12/new-tool-saml-raider-v1-1-1-saml2-burp-extension/

Another great BApp for Burp Suite, SAMLReQuest, is detailed here -- https://www.insinuator.net/2016/06/samlrequest-burpsuite-extention/

This author went into detail for an XXE security bug found in a SAML app -- https://seanmelia.wordpress.com/2016/01/09/xxe-via-saml/ -- but I really enjoyed this post from the SendSafely and Gotham Digital Science teams -- https://blog.sendsafely.com/web-based-single-sign-on-and-the-dangers-of-saml-xml-parsing

Comment: https://breakdev.org/evilginx-advanced-phishing-with-two-factor-authentication-bypass/

Comment: https://medium.com/@FreedomCoder/following-the-white-rabbit-5e392e3f6fb9

Comment: https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/475445

Comment: https://epi052.gitlab.io/notes-to-self/blog/2019-03-07-how-to-test-saml-a-methodology/

Comment: https://github.com/simplesamlphp/SAML-tracer